# Sessions reduced by 50% after varnish cache implementation

Tags: caching, google-analytics, varnish

After implementation of varnish cache on apache server, sessions are reduced to half on google analytics. Since it is JS code that runs on client side, shouldn't be affecting this. What could be the issue?